# I am now using Parse to develop an APP, but the notification is not available to specific user

Tags: ios, parse-platform, notifications

I followed toturials of Parse to develop an APP and it works well on my iphone and most of others', which imply that I written most part of the code correctly. However, when it comes to some specefic users, they are just never able to receive the notification. I am quite sure that they have allow the notification on this APP through system settings. Even reinstall the APP does not fix this issue. It seems that I may need you folks experience to help me out, because I am really not sure what's wrong. What could be the possible reason for that? Let me know if you want the code part of the APP :)

Comment: Anything in common about the equipment used by these users?

Comment: @TommieC. Hi, thougth it's not safe to say that all these users' equipmnt is not in common, what I can say for sure is that my girl friend's is quite normal and able to receive notification from other APPs smoothly

Comment: Which device is showing the issue iPhone 4,5,6 or iPads? Which are not showing the issue?

Comment: @TommieC. Based on current situation, only iPhone6 seems to be like that

Answer (score 0):

You can log in to [parse.com](http://parse.com) and go to the **Push** tab to see a log of all push notifications that have been sent. If any of them have failed, it should give information as to why.

You can also check your **Installation** class to see if all the devices using push notifications have been properly registered with a device token.